# EntityNotFoundException when removing from OneToMany collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities connected with a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship.

```
@Entity
class One {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "one", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Many> manies;

  // ...
}

@Entity
class Many {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "one_id", nullable = false)
  private One one;

  // ...
}
```

When I want to remove a `Many` instance, I remove it from its `One`'s `manies` `Set` and delete it from the database. If I take the same `One` instance and save it again (because I changed anything, it doesn't have to be related to the relationship), I get an exception:

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find test.Many with id 12345

The ID (in this example 12345) is the ID of the just removed entity. Note that removal of the entity 12345 succeeded: The transaction commits successfully and the row is removed from the database.

Adding and removing instances is done with Spring Data repositories. Removing looks more or less like this:

```
one.getManies().remove(manyToRemove);
oneDao.save(one);
manyDao.delete(manyToRemove);
```

I debugged a little and found out that the `Set` is a Hibernate `PersistentSet` which contains a field `storedSnapshot`. This in turn is another `Set` that still references the removed entity. I have no idea why this reference is not removed from the snapshot but I suspect this is the problem: I think Hibernate tries to remove the entity a second time because it's in the snapshot but not in the actual collection. I searched for quite a while but I didn't encounter others with a similar problem.

I use Hibernate 4.2.2 and Spring Data 1.6.0.

Am I doing something inherently wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem.

A workaround is to replace the entire collection.

```
Set<Many> maniesBkp = one.getManies(); // Instance of PersistentSet
maniesBkp.remove(manyToRemove);

Set<Many> manies = new HashSet<Many>();
manies.addAll(maniesBkp);

one.setManies(manies);

...
manyDao.delete(manyToRemove);
...
oneDao.save(one);
```

Answer (score 2):

As your `@OneToMany` relation has `orphanRemoval = true`, you don't have to explicitly remove the child element from the database - just remove it from the collection and save the parent element.

Comment: Well, I thought so, too but alas, it doesn't work. BTW I also played around with cascading but this seemed to create more problems than it solved. That's why I decided to manage both sides manually which works fine apart from the little issue here...

Comment: And removing the `orphanRemoval = true` when managing everything by hand has not worked out?

Comment: You're right that this is probably not needed anymore. Unfortunately removing it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Try add CascadeType.REMOVE and orphanRemoval

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "one", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Than perform delete following

```
one.getManies().remove(manyToRemove);
oneDao.save(one);
```

Edited:
I have created POC, look on the UserRepositoryIntegrationTest.departmentTestCase ([code](https://github.com/ssledz/spring-fundamentals/blob/master/spring-data/src/test/java/pl/softech/learning/repositories/UserRepositoryIntegrationTest.java))

Comment: This doesn't do anything. :( I know it should work, but it plain doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, please publish your sample code somewhere (in the github for example) Let it be maven project

Comment: I tried your POC. I don't know what to tell you. If I debug your test, the stored snapshot gets updated with every removal. In my application it does not.

Comment: In addition to that, when I use the equivalent of your code in my application, persist does not set the IDs of the entities in the referenced set; they simply stay `null`.

Comment: I cannot publish the code; it belongs to the company I work for. But I try to work with your example and somehow replicate the behavior. So far without luck.

Comment: So I can't help. I wish you luck